# UIViewController not responding to NSNotifications

Tags: ios

I have a `UIViewController` that's not responding to `NSNotifications`. I'm sure the action that is kicked off by the notification works. What could be wrong with my setup?

I use a singleton to load a `feedViewController` from the `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunching`. This `feedViewController` keeps a reference to a `deckViewController`, and this `deckViewController` reliably sends the notifications to which the `feedViewController` should be observing. Yet the notifications are never received. I made sure that the `singleton` keeps a strong reference to the view controller that should be receiving the notifications.

In the `singleton` that holds a reference to the notification observer:

```
 // .h file
 @property (nonatomic) ROFeedViewController *feedViewController;

 // .m file
 _feedViewController = [[ROFeedViewController alloc] init];
    IIViewDeckController *deckController = [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:_feedViewController leftViewController:leftController rightViewController:rightController];
    _feedViewController.deckController = deckController;
```

In notification observer (`ROFeedViewControler`):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(viewDeckPanned:) name:@"ViewDeckPanned" object:_deckController];
    ...
}

- (void)viewDeckPanned:(NSNotification *)notification {
    float offset = [(NSNumber *)[notification object] floatValue];
    if (offset > 0) {
        _leftButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(offset * M_PI / 180.0);
    } else {
        _rightButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(offset * M_PI / 180.0);
    }
}
```

Notifications reliable get sent from the notification sender (`IIViewDeckController`):

```
- (void)notifyDidChangeOffset:(CGFloat)offset orientation:(IIViewDeckOffsetOrientation)orientation panning:(BOOL)panning {
    [self performDelegate:@selector(viewDeckController:didChangeOffset:orientation:panning:) offset:offset orientation:orientation panning:panning];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ViewDeckPanned" object:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:offset]];
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You setup:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(viewDeckPanned:) name:@"ViewDeckPanned" object:_deckController];
```

Which means that you are listening to notification of name "ViewDeckPanned" that come **from** _deckController (since object: parameter is supposed to define the **notification sender**).

But, that the same time, you post notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ViewDeckPanned" object:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:offset]];
```

and you tell that [NSNumber numberWithFloat:offset] is a sender. Since `_deckController` and instance of `NSNumber` do not match each other, you get no notification info in your observer.

Simple change would be to pass `nil` as `object:` parameter (in both places - where you add observer, and where you post notification), and if you want to pass NSNumber along with notification, then create userInfo dictionary that contains it.